# Node + Google Street View: How to check if a Street View is available in a certain radius

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use Node and Google Street View together (Google doesn't officially support this). However, one of the things I noticed about Street View is that if you supply it with a point that doesn't have a Street View... it doesn't do anything...

I would like to use Node to reference the Google Maps API (Street View specifically) to find a point within a radius that has a Street View.

I saw a few packages like: https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps
but the docs aren't all that helpful. I know this API can be used to generate an image of a Street View, but I'm looking to find a point so that I can send it to a client so that they can display an interactive Street View (Street View Service).

Is any of this at all possible? This may have been worded a little bit weirdly... any questions just let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this sample provided just that: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service

on init, they add a on click listener with `sv.getPanoramaByLocation(event.latLng, 50, processSVData);`, which let the street view search a point with data within 50m of the given point, then call the `processSVData`. Within the call back, they check if there is any points returned by checking `if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK)`, if so, the location that contains a street view is return in `data.location.pano`, which is what they used to add a marker.

I think you should be able to do the same thing in the back end too.

Comment: The problem I'm running in to is that google is not defined due to the first couple lines of that code.